# How to list custom added field in sync settings in mailchip integration with bigcommerce

Tags: mailchimp, bigcommerce

> Hello I have integrate mailchimp in bigcommerce.  I have added one
>   custom field in MailChimp which is also displayed in bigcommerce apps.
>   [image]
>   and I have also added Due date section in Advance setting->account
>   signup form->address field. 
>   [image]
>   but in MailChimp app sync setting there
>   are no options to select the due date.
>   [image]
>    Is their other process to add the field
>   to list on select option n sync setting 'manage your data' section.

Comment: Hey there, have you reached out to Mailchimp support? This sounds like either a product support question or a feature request, depending on whether that's intended functionality in their app. But as an external developer, you wouldn't have any access to modify the behavior of the Mailchimp app itself.

Comment: Mailchimp replay as "Unfortunately there is not an option to sync that field with mailchimp from Bigcommerce. I can submit that as feedback to the devs to see if this can be improved upon in future versions of the application on your behalf though. I do understand that this limitation will prevent you from triggering an automation based on the specific field but at this time there is not a work around to this issue. "